# pppd: short connection time

Tags: linux, ppp

**Problem Description**

I am using a ublox SARA-R410 modem and `pppd` with a Linux host over UART.  I sometimes see very short connection intervals where seemingly `pppd` forces a reconnect without a logged reason.  Eventually (on a restart after IPCP timeout) `pppd` achieves a stable IPv4 connection.

**Debugging**

Here is the syslog as `pppd` starts and the issue occurs, then eventually times out for a restart (which succeeds):

```
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Serial connection established.
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: using channel 21
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Using interface ppp0
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/mux0
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: expect (OK)
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: ^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: AT+CSQ^M^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: +CSQ: 31,99^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: ^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: OK
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: send (ATS0=1^M^M)
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: expect (OK)
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: ^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: ATS0=1^M^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: OK
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: send (ATDT*99***1#^M^M)
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: expect (CONNECT)
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: ^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: ATDT*99***1#^M^M
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: CONNECT
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:13:16 chat[4470]: send (^M)
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -e -t 180 -f /etc/ppp/chat-isp finished (pid 4468), status = 0x0
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Serial connection established.
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: using channel 21
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Using interface ppp0
Mar 06 17:13:16 pppd[4467]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/mux0
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf8e9941f> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf8e9941f> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: No auth is possible
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <auth chap MD5>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf8e9941f> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: No auth is possible
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <auth chap MD5>]
Mar 06 17:13:17 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf8e9941f> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:19 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:19 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:19 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:19 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:19 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:19 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:20 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:20 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8d12075b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:20 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:20 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:20 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8d12075b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:20 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8d12075b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8d12075b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:21 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:22 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:22 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xec8d3bf0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:22 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:22 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:22 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xec8d3bf0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:22 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf03d27ed> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:23 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xec8d3bf0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:23 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xec8d3bf0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mar 06 17:13:23 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:23 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:23 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x5 magic=0xf03d27ed]
Mar 06 17:13:23 pppd[4467]: rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x5 magic=0xf03d27ed]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x0]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x0 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x0]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x0 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:24 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:25 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:26 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3]
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3]
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:28 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x4]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x6 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x4]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x6 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:29 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x7 <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x7 <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:30 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6]
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x6]
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x8 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:31 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6]
Mar 06 17:13:31 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x6]
Mar 06 17:13:31 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x8 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:31 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:32 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7]
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x7 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7]
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:33 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x7 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x8]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x9 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x8]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x9 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:34 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x9]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xa <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xb <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x9]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xa <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:35 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xb <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xa]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0xb <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xa]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0xb <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:37 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xb]
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xc <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0xb <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xb]
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xc <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:38 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0xb <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xc]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xc]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0xc <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xc]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xc]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0xc <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:39 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xd]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xd <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xd]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xd <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:40 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xe]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0xe <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xe]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0xe <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:42 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xf]
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xf <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0xf <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xf]
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xf <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:43 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0xf <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x10]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x10]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0xf <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x10 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x10]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x10]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0xf <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Mar 06 17:13:44 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x10 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x11]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x11]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x10 <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x11 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x11]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x11]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x10 <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:46 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x11 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x12]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x11 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x12]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x11 <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: local  IP address 10.67.100.135
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
Mar 06 17:13:47 pppd[4467]: secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x13]
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x13 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x13]
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4 bytes.
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:48 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x13 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:51 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:51 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:54 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:54 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:57 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:13:57 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:00 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:00 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:03 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:03 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:06 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:06 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:09 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:09 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:12 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:12 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:15 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:15 pppd[4467]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.67.100.135> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Mar 06 17:14:18 pppd[4467]: IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Mar 06 17:14:18 pppd[4467]: IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Mar 06 17:14:18 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x4 "No network protocols running"]
Mar 06 17:14:18 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x4 "No network protocols running"]
Mar 06 17:14:21 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x5 "No network protocols running"]
Mar 06 17:14:21 pppd[4467]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x5 "No network protocols running"]
Mar 06 17:14:24 pppd[4467]: Connection terminated.
Mar 06 17:14:24 pppd[4467]: Connection terminated.
Mar 06 17:14:24 chat[4635]: abort on (BUSY)
Mar 06 17:14:24 chat[4635]: abort on (ERROR)
Mar 06 17:14:24 chat[4635]: abort on (NO DIALTONE)
Mar 06 17:14:24 chat[4635]: send (+++)
Mar 06 17:14:24 pppd[4467]: Sending break
Mar 06 17:14:24 chat[4635]: send (\dATH^M)
Mar 06 17:14:25 pppd[4467]: [4B blob data]
Mar 06 17:14:25 pppd[4467]: Querying CSQ
Mar 06 17:14:25 pppd[4467]: [1B blob data]
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: OK
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: AT+CSQ
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: +CSQ: 31,99
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: OK
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: AT+COPS=2
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: OK
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: PDP context detached
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: [1B blob data]
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -e -t 10 -f /etc/ppp/disconnect-chat finished (pid 4633), status = 0x0
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Serial link disconnected.
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Modem hangup
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: expect (^M)
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: ATH^M
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: send (AT+CSQ^M^M)
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: expect (OK)
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: ^M
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: OK
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:14:25 chat[4635]: send (AT+COPS=2^M^M)
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: expect (OK)
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: ^M
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: AT+CSQ^M^M
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: +CSQ: 31,99^M
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: ^M
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: OK
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: send (AT+CPSMS?^M^M)
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: expect (OK)
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: ^M
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: AT+COPS=2^M^M
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: OK
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]:  -- got it
Mar 06 17:14:26 chat[4635]: send (AT&F^M^M)
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -e -t 10 -f /etc/ppp/disconnect-chat finished (pid 4633), status = 0x0
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Serial link disconnected.
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Modem hangup
Mar 06 17:14:26 pppd[4467]: Exit.
... restarts here and obtains stable IPv4 address right away...
```

If I watch `ifconfig` during the above, I see `ppp0` obtain an IPv4 address then lose it, over and over.  The interface only has an IPv4 address for a fraction of a second.

This is my pppd `options` file:

```
debug
/dev/mux0
460800
mtu 1500
mru 1500
modem
local
crtscts
lock
idle 60
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -e -t 180 -f /etc/ppp/chat-isp"
disconnect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -e -t 10 -f /etc/ppp/disconnect-chat"
asyncmap 0
#noipdefault
noauth
nobsdcomp
#novjccomp
#noaccomp
#noccp
#nodeflate
#nopcomp
#nopredictor1
#novj
defaultroute
usepeerdns
:
```

As seen in commented lines above, I've tried disabling various compression options without luck.  With any *single* compression option disabled, the issue still occurs.

**Questions**

I would really like the link bringup to happen in a consistent way, without timing out and restarting.

Is there anything else I should try apart from more combinations of pppd `options`? Anything else I should look into for debugging apart from the syslog?

Answer (score 1):

After digging for a few hours and adding prints into `pppd`, I determined that the teardown I described in my initial post is happening from `pppd/fsm.c` in the function `fsm_rconfreq()`

```
static void
fsm_rconfreq(f, id, inp, len)
    fsm *f;
    u_char id;
    u_char *inp;
    int len;
{
    int code, reject_if_disagree;

    switch( f->state ){
    case CLOSED:
        /* Go away, we're closed */
        fsm_sdata(f, TERMACK, id, NULL, 0);
        return;
    case CLOSING:
    case STOPPING:
        return;

    case OPENED:
        /* Go down and restart negotiation */
//////// BEGIN EDIT /////////
//        if( f->callbacks->down )
//            (*f->callbacks->down)(f); /* Inform upper layers */
//        fsm_sconfreq(f, 0);           /* Send initial Configure-Request */
//        f->state = REQSENT;
//        break;
//////// END EDIT /////////

    case STOPPED:
        /* Negotiation started by our peer */
        fsm_sconfreq(f, 0);             /* Send initial Configure-Request */
        f->state = REQSENT;
        break;
    }
```

The commented section of code calls `ipcp_down()` via function pointer, which prints link statistics.

With the code commented out as shown, I see much more stable link bring-up.

Not sure if this is a bug in `pppd` or with the modem.  This is using pppd-2.4.7 in case that matters.